# Is there any easy way to get current list from AsyncListDiffer after Diff calculation finished?

Tags: android, android-asynclistdiffer

I want to get the current list from AsyncListDiffer after the diff calculation finishes, for the sake of Unit Testing. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you using List Adapter?

Comment: When you submit a list to list adapter it provides a callback.

Comment: ```adapter.submitList(postList, () -> { // adapter.getCurrentList(); });```

Comment: I am doing it for RecyclerView.Adapter